# Friendly Format for date and time

Tags: list-view

Is there a way to reproduce the friendly date format to show minutes since last modified.  When I modified the view style from 'default' to 'basic table' it only shows the full date and time instead of the minutes since.

Comment: what exact date format you want to display ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try column formatting to display date format of your preference. You can find on how date ranges can be used for formatting column at below link.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#apply-formatting-based-on-date-ranges

This link has complex use case but it would give you ideas on how to modify it for your requirement.